# How to group row value using SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I want to group same yAxisTitle in SQL Server, below image shows my data.

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

Query I used:

```
select 
    q.questionId, q.questionName, 
    p.perspectiveTitle, x.xAxisTitle, y.yAxisTitle, c.value 
from 
    coaching_questionPerspectiveMap as c 
inner join  
    Coaching_question as q on c.questionId = q.questionId 
inner join 
    Coaching_perspective as p on c.perspectiveId = p.perspectiveId 
inner join 
    coaching_xAxisData x on c.xAxisDataId = x.xAxisDataId 
inner join 
    coaching_yAxisData y on c.yAxisDataId = y.yAxisDataId
where 
    q.questionId = 14 
    and p.perspectiveId = 1 
order by 
    c.sort
```

Please provide any solution?

Thanks,

Comment: post your question a little bit clearly..

Comment: In your expected results you haven't grouped the data, you have just ordered it by yAxisTitle. Is this what you want?

Comment: yes, i didn't able to group the rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the data ordered so that it shows in groups of yAxisTitle, use this:

```
select 
    q.questionId, q.questionName, 
    p.perspectiveTitle, x.xAxisTitle, y.yAxisTitle, c.value 
from 
    coaching_questionPerspectiveMap as c 
inner join  
    Coaching_question as q on c.questionId = q.questionId 
inner join 
    Coaching_perspective as p on c.perspectiveId = p.perspectiveId 
inner join 
    coaching_xAxisData x on c.xAxisDataId = x.xAxisDataId 
inner join 
    coaching_yAxisData y on c.yAxisDataId = y.yAxisDataId
where 
    q.questionId = 14 
    and p.perspectiveId = 1 
order by 
    y.yAxisTitle, c.sort
```